# Count and merge consecutive patterns

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, python, perl, duplicate

I'm searching for a short snippet to find, count and merge *consecutive* duplicates using standard tools or a common scripting language.

Say our input is:

```
1 2 2 2 7 22 a b b c c c c c d dd 2 2 c c
```

And as output we would like to have something *similar* to:

```
1 3*2 7 22 a 2*b 5*c d dd 2*2 2*c
```

It is important to keep the order and to merge only *consecutive* patterns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
printf '%s\n' 1 2 2 2 7 22 a b b c c c c c d dd 2 2 c c | uniq -c
```

Output:

```
      1 1
      3 2
      1 7
      1 22
      1 a
      2 b
      5 c
      1 d
      1 dd
      2 2
      2 c
```

It's simple and easy (and *similar*).

To get your format:

```
printf '%s\n' 1 2 2 2 7 22 a b b c c c c c d dd 2 2 c c |
  uniq -c | sed 's/^ *//;s/^1 //;s/ /*/' | paste -sd' ' -
```